# .htaccess RewriteRule error

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I have these lines in .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Now, I'd like to add the following into the .htaccess, so I can redirect all users to http://www.mydomain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, I just added the code above in my existing .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule . index.php
```

But, It doesn't work as I expect.

Please teach me how I am supposed to write in this case.

Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: "But, It doesn't work as I expect." --- what do you expect and how exactly does it work?

Comment: redirecting users accessing http://mydomain.com to http:/www.mydomain.com works.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php

these lines don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect to the www subdomain first, then forward the request to your index.php file. Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.).+$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```